# Can I set a condition in my YAML script, to have the pipeline choose an agent depending which agent is available but to only run the job defined?

Tags: conditional-statements, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Basically, I want to build a project that can be built both on windows and Linux. I want to define two jobs, windowsBuild and linuxBuild. I want the pipeline only ran the windows build if the agent chosen is a windows agent and to only run the Linux build if the agent chosen is a Linux agent. Also, I want the default agent to be the windows one, I want it to only run on the Linux if the windows one is unavailable, and in the scenario that both are unavailable it should wait for the windows agent.

p.s I am using self-hosted agents; fun fact, I accidently deleted Microsoft hosted agents and don't know how to replace them :)

Anyone know how I can do this? Would really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one job named Check. Then add powershell task.

Create  script to check agent status.

Use rest api [Agents - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get windows and linux agent status. And `exit` based on the agnet status.

Set job condition.

E.g. if windows agent is unavailable and linux agent is available, powershell task  `exit 1` (Job check failed)  and will trigger job B.

```
- job: buildA
  displayName: buildA
  dependsOn: Check
  condition: succeeded()
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest
  
  steps:
  - script: echo "windows-latest"

- job: buildB
  displayName: buildB
  dependsOn: Check
  pool: 
    vmImage:  ubuntu-latest
  condition: failed()
  steps:
  - script: echo "ubuntu-latest"
```